# mongodb collections become empty

Tags: mongodb

I observed several times that (probably after server restarts) all my collections become empty.

I still see DB files that around 100mb 
alarm.0
alarm.ns

But no object in collections.

I checked logs, no exceptions there. 
Any ideas?

many thanks,
Anton

Comment: Could you elaborate your problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I fond the problem. It is not a technical one though.

I found a strange database with the name Attention with one document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5999603bab66b2066ac16a00"),
    "email" : "datarequest@secmail.pro",
    "btc_wallet" : "1E7TCtPCCwd1wPyFHXrGbNECfaEzMjzGHg",
    "note" : "We have your data. Your database is backed up to our servers. If you want to restore it, then send 0.2 BTC and text me to email, just send your IP-address and payment info. Messages without payment info will be ignored."
}
```

Forgot to close port that I opened.
Hope guys will pay at least something for storing my useless data.